# Can't display content of xml elements in an unordered list in the proper way

Tags: javascript, xml, html, list

I am trying to display the content of specific elements that i load from an xml file using javascript,but it doesn't work. 
Here is my xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <book><title>Alice in Wonderland</title>
 <author>Lewis Carroll</author>
      <year>1866</year>
      <comment> Alice falls down a rabbit hole into a fantasy world </comment>
      <comment> Considered to be one of the best examples of the literary nonsense genre </comment>
      <comment> Novel written by English author Charles Lutwidge Dodgson </comment>
   </book>
```

I want to display the content of all "comment" tags in a div element as an unordered list using javascript.
The result i got is the content but not as an unordered list.
Here is what i am trying and it does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
   function loadXMLDoc(doc) { 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
         request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      } else { 
         request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
      } 
      request.open("GET",doc,false); 
      request.send(""); 
      return request.responseXML; 
   }

   function displayunordered(doc) {
      xmlDoc  = "";
      xmlDoc  = loadXMLDoc(doc);

      comment = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("comment");  
      document.getElementById('unordered').innerHTML = "<ul>";//insert opening ul tag

      //pass from all comment elements
      for(var i = 0 ; i < comment.length; i++){
         var com = comment[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         document.getElementById('unordered').innerHTML += "<li>" + com;
         document.getElementById('unordered').innerHTML += "</li>";
      }

      document.getElementById('unordered').innerHTML += "</ul>"; //insert closing ul tag

   }//end of function displayunordered

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- div to display the result -->
    <div id="unordered"> comments elements</div>
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick="displayunordered('one-book.xml')">Show comments elements unordered</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell why?

Answer (score 1):

Appending `.innerHTML` the way you are doing will not work. You should append to a temporary variable, then assign that temporary variable to `.innerHTML`.

```
var html = "<ul>";
for(var i = 0 ; i < comment.length;i++){
   var com = comment[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   html += "<li>" + com;
   html += "</li>";
}
html += "</ul>";
document.getElementById('unordered').innerHTML = html;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/gfYdG/) of that part (assuming the XML is already loaded).

Comment: `.innerHTML` doesn't append plain text. It appends HTML. So when you do something like `tag.innerHTML = '<p>';` you are actually appending `<p></p>`. I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/cR3Er/) that shows that. I added one `<p>` and one `</p>`, but the result (in the alert box) is very different.